# Auto logout not working when I does not attend the call or cut the call in middle of my application

Tags: android

I'm developing android application. The following are the settings details **android:minSdkVersion="8" & android:targetSdkVersion="17"**

In my application, I'm implementing the auto logout after some specific time.

For eg: Assume auto logout time after 2 minutes. If the application in from or background ,If it is idle then after 2 minutes it will successfully logout.

The problem is if any call is comes means in the middle of my application (my application's any screen or any activity is running or is in front). At that time if i attend or cut the call means then auto logout works fine.

But **if i not do anything (not attend the call nor cut the call) after some time call automatically cuts but here my auto logout not works fine.**

My question details in short :Auto logout is works fine. But one scenario is not working. That scenario I'm working in my application ,at that time a call is comes means, At that time I'm not doing anything (not attend a call or not cut the call),So after some time call cut and my application is shows at that time auto logout not works fine. The time takes from when application shows after cut the call. But i need to calculate the auto logout time from when call arises (that when ring is comes).

All your ideas are welcome.

Comment: sorry, it is really hard to understand your issue. Could you rephrase?

Comment: What do you mean by not working properly? time is getting reset.. or auto-logout itself not working properly.

Comment: You can register broadcast when any call comes,,,..that broadcast will do the task of logout

Answer (score 1):

Did you try these?

- Alarm Manager sending a Broadcast
- If your app is in the foreground, you can simply use onPause() of your activity to start the timer
- If you want to handle calls especially, listen for Call State changes in a Broadcast receiver, [see](https://web.archive.org/web/20210127130519/http://www.tutorialforandroid.com/2009/01/get-phone-state-when-someone-is-calling_22.html).